# Probability of two players choosing at least one common number (with different drawing attempts)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that in a raffle box there are $K$ possible numbers to choose from.
There are two players, i.e., A and B.

Player A starts the game by extracting randomly $N_A$ numbers out of the $K$ possible numbers. The same number cannot be extracted twice, i.e., no repetitions.

After player A has extracted his $N_A$ numbers, numbers are re-inserted into the raffle box and  player B starts extracting randomly $N_B$ numbers out of the $K$ possible numbers, again with no repetitions.

Now, what is the probability of player B extracting (in his $N_B$ attempts) **at least one** of the number that was extracted by player A (in his $N_A$ attempts)?

Note that $N_A$ and $N_B$ may or may not be different (in general $N_B\neq N_A$).

---

*Example: There are $K=10$ numbers. Player A can extract $N_A=2$ numbers, say it extract numbers 3 and 4. Player B can now extract $N_B=4$ numbers. What is the probability that player B extracts, in his 4 attempts, number 3 or number 4?*

Comment: A chooses $N_A$ from K.   In order to have NO duplicates, B would then have to choose $N_B$ from $K - N_A$ as opposed to his total choice of choosing from $N_B$ from $K$

Comment: so in order for what you want to be FALSE B has to choose from {1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10} which is 4 from 8 - which is how many ways?  compared to 4 from 10?  The ratio would give you the complement of what you want, so you would subtract it from 1 to get the value you need.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Calculate the probability that the two players have no number in common.

This means that the $N_B$ numbers chosen by $B$ are among $K-N_A$ possible numbers.

Comment: Does it mean calculating  $1-\binom{N_B}{K-N_A}$? Shouldn't I be considering also the occurrence of all permutations?

Comment: @mgiordi $1-\binom{N_B}{K-N_A}<0$. Note that $1-\binom{K-N_A}{N_B}$ counts all the good choices, you need to divide by all the possible choices for $B$ to get a probability.

Answer (score 1):

Well if the first person picks $N_a$ numbers out of $K$ then they chose $N_a/K$ percent of numbers.  Now let's say that the second person just picks $1$ number.  The odds that they chose one of the first ones would be $N_a/K$.  Therefore the odds that he didn't is $1-N_a/K$.  Now if the second player picks $2$ numbers out of the $K$.  then the odds that he didn't pick any of the same would be the odds that he didn't the first time times the odds that he didn't the second time: $1-N_a/K$ times $1-N_a/(K-1)$ which is $(1-N_a/K)(1-N_a/(K-1))$.

In general it's:

$(1-N_a/K)*(1-N_a/(K-1))*(1-N_a/(K-2))*...*(1-N_a/(K-N_b+1))$

Example, $K=10, N_a=2, N_b=3$:

probability of picking ALL different numbers = $(1-2/10)*(1-2/9)*(1-2/8) = 0.466$
probability of picking at least 1 same = $1 - 0.466 = 0.533$

I hope that answers your question.